# Issue in retrieving date fields from excel sheet (Selenium Webdriver) causing a argument type mismatch exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im working with Selenium Webdriver on a script which retrieves data from an excel sheet. The script has date fields and when I run it, I get an argument type mismatch constructor exception when I have a date like 09/10/2013, but if I enter 19/10/2013 then the script runs :/ 
I changed the format of d cells in d excel sheet also, but in d formula of it is as 9/10/2013, maybe that’s the issue. Any idea to overcome this?

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML you're trying to operate on and the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had the same issue. What I did was, I changed the cell format in excel to "Text". And everything worked fine for me. I was using Java as the script language.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. I happened to change the data formats of the particular cells and "text" format worked for me as well. :)